# Strange dimension behaviour: needs both dimension 2 and 3 unsure why

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to convert a simple model to TFLite and run into the following issue with dimensions.

I've already tried using perm=[1,0] and perm=[0,2,1] the first one will generate an error requiring 3 dimensions and the 2nd one will generate an error requiring 2 dimensions.

```
import tensorflow as tf

captions = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[5,1024], name='captions')
cap_i = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda q: q[0][:5,:])([captions])
cap_iT = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda query:tf.transpose(query, 
perm=[0,2,1]))(cap_i)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[captions], outputs=[cap_iT])
model.save('my_model.hd5')
converter = 
tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('my_model.hd5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_modelfile.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

> ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 3 for 'lambda_1/transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [5,1024], [3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a nice way to fix the inputs using a compatible operation in TFLite.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import numpy as np

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
initial_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None,5,1024))
cap_i = tf.strided_slice(initial_input, [0,0,0], [0,5,1024], [1,1,1], shrink_axis_mask=1)
cap_i_reshaped =tf.reshape(cap_i,[1,5,1024])
cap_iT = tf.transpose(cap_i_reshaped, perm=[0,2,1])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf.io.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '', 'train.pbtxt')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [initial_input], [cap_iT])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, 
tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open('converted_model.tflite', "wb").write(tflite_model)
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the error in two different places.

You are throwing away the batch size dimension in the first `Lambda` with  `q[0]`. You should not do this, you will need the batch dimension at the end of the Keras model (probably the location of the other error). Although you are passing `[captions]` inside a list, it is probably automatically getting the element inside the list because it's a single tensor.

The message in your question is certainly in the second `Lambda`, where you have a tensor with two dimensions `[5,1024]` (because you threw away the batch size in the first `Lambda`) and you are trying to permute 3 dimensions with `[0,2,1]`.